# MySQL (Hottest) SORT BY 2 different parameters(Most liked in less time)

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to figure out how to make `"Hottest Posts"` where posts are selected ordering by `most upvoted in shortest time`.

I have got 2 database tables:

fun_posts:

[image: Image1]

fun_post_upvotes:

[image: Image2]

And latest of my code, that still dosn't work:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM fun_posts, (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) FROM fun_post_upvotes GROUP BY image_id)
            WHERE id = image_id ORDER BY id DESC, upvotes DESC");
```

Comment: What are your expected results?? You may need a join

Comment: Define "shortest time"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this query:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare=("SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                           FROM fun_post_upvotes 
                                           WHERE image_id=fun_posts.id
                                           GROUP BY image_id)
                               FROM fun_posts
                               ORDER BY fun_posts,id DESC, fun_posts.upvotes DESC");
```

Comment: At this point get error : SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, try now